# Filter parent by it child ids

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, which look like this (simplified):

***Operations:***

```
|operation_id|description|created_at|
|------------|-----------|----------|
|           1|        abc|2020-04-04|
```

***Transactions***

```
|transaction_id|amount|created_at|user_id|operation_id|type|
|--------------|------|----------|-------|------------|----|
|             1|   400|2020-04-04|      1|           1|  tr|
|             2|   400|2020-04-04|      2|           1|  tr|
```

How can I find all operations in which **transaction.user_id**'s intersects with an array of user ids?
E.g. for array **[1, 2]** there will be match (operation_id = 1), because both ids were in **transaction.user_id** for that operation. For array **[1, 3]** there will be no matches because it only partially matches **transaction.user_id** that belongs to a specific operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate the user_ids and then compare them with your array:

```
select o.*
from operations o
join (
  select operation_id, array_agg(user_id order by user_id) as user_ids
  from transactions t
  group by operation_id
) t on t.operation_id = o.operation_id and user_ids = array[1,2];
```

Alternatively you could use an IN condition:

```
select o.*
from operations o
where operation_id in (select operation_id
                       from transactions t
                       group by operation_id
                       having array_agg(user_id order by user_id) = array[1,2]);
```

The `order by user_id` in the array_agg() call is important because equality of arrays depends on the order of elements. `array[1,2]` is not equal to `array[2,1]`

So you need to make sure that the user IDs in the array used for the join condition are also sorted properly.