# Filter parent by it child ids performance optimized way

Tags: postgresql

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63484304/filter-parent-by-it-child-ids) previously and the answer provided not good enough for my case.

---

**Original problem:**

I have two tables, which look like this (simplified):

***Operations:***

```
|operation_id|description|created_at|
|------------|-----------|----------|
|           1|        abc|2020-04-04|
```

***Transactions***

```
|transaction_id|amount|created_at|user_id|operation_id|type|
|--------------|------|----------|-------|------------|----|
|             1|   400|2020-04-04|      1|           1|  tr|
|             2|   400|2020-04-04|      2|           1|  tr|
```

How can I find all operations in which **transaction.user_id**'s intersects with an array of user ids?
E.g. for array **[1, 2]** there will be match (operation_id = 1), because both ids were in **transaction.user_id** for that operation. For array **[1, 3]** there will be no matches because it only partially matches **transaction.user_id** that belongs to a specific operation.

---

I have a large set of data ~20mil rows. So it's taking long time and disk space to do this query
(*query from the previous answer provided by [a-horse-with-no-name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)*):

```sql
select o.*
from operations o
join (
  select operation_id, array_agg(user_id order by user_id) as user_ids
  from transactions t
  group by operation_id
) t on t.operation_id = o.operation_id and user_ids = array[1,2];
```

QueryPlan (6.5 mil dataset):

```sql
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                     
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1296849.10..1296999.14 rows=10 width=120) (actual time=8871.152..14749.177 rows=8 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1296849.10..1466416.65 rows=11301 width=120) (actual time=8620.570..14498.587 rows=8 loops=1)
         ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=1296848.66..1379394.19 rows=11301 width=48) (actual time=8619.037..14489.532 rows=8 loops=1)
               Group Key: t.operation_id
               Filter: (array_agg(t.user_id ORDER BY t.user_id) = '{100001,1000001}'::integer[])
               Rows Removed by Filter: 6505868
               ->  Sort  (cost=1296848.66..1313062.73 rows=6485628 width=20) (actual time=8230.674..9245.698 rows=6505884 loops=1)
                     Sort Key: t.operation_id
                     Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 191016kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on transaction t  (cost=0.00..297024.29 rows=6485628 width=20) (actual time=0.204..3908.583 rows=6505884 loops=1)
                           Filter: (user_id = ANY ('{100001,1000001}'::integer[]))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 6515670
         ->  Index Scan using pk_operation_id on operation o  (cost=0.43..7.69 rows=1 width=120) (actual time=1.124..1.124 rows=1 loops=8)
               Index Cond: (operation_id = t.operation_id)
 Planning Time: 3.399 ms
 JIT:
   Functions: 16
   Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
   Timing: Generation 2.468 ms, Inlining 53.556 ms, Optimization 100.695 ms, Emission 94.838 ms, Total 251.557 ms
 Execution Time: 14998.817 ms
```

I also tried to add an integer array for the operation that lists all user ids that belong to this operation, for faster search. But the index is too large (gin) more than 1gb.

```sql
ALTER TABLE public.operations ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS accounts integer[] NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';

CREATE INDEX idx_operation_accounts ON public.operations USING gin (accounts);
```

Is there any better approach for this problem?

Comment: "Intersects with" means they have at least one element in common, which based on your counterexample of [1,3] is clearly not what you meant.  Which leaves us not knowing what it is you did mean.  Do you want the list of user ids to be exactly equal to the provided list, or to fully contain it but perhaps with some left ever members as well?

Comment: "I also tried to add an integer array for the operation that lists all user ids that belong to this operation, for faster search."  This is vague. Please show the CREATE statement for this index.

Comment: @jjanes if all ids in array exist for the specific operation (operation can have more user_ids, counting only those in the array) that's a match if at least one id is not present - skip the whole operation. UPD. added index example

Comment: I am also a bit surprised that the execution isn't using a parallel Seq Scan and Group By. What is the value of `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` and how may CPUs does your database server have? Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name **max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2**, 12 cores, postgresql 12.2

Comment: Does turning off JIT (`set jit = off;`)  change anything? What if you increase `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` to e.g. 4 or 8? Does it use a parallel query then?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name tried all your suggestions, it doesn't change anything, w/o jit it's a bit slower actually

Comment: What is the current value of your `work_mem` parameter ?  `SHOW work_mem;`. If too small, you could try to execute for instance : `SET work_mem TO '1 GB';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the index is too large (gin) more than 1gb.

I think you have an unreasonable standard, if 1GB to index 20e6 rows is too large.

With the "accounts" column on operations being correctly populated and indexed, you could forget the join to transactions and just do:

```
select * from operations where accounts @> array[1,2];
```

But, if the values of 1 and 2 each show up millions of time, this might not be all that efficient.  It would have to find all the rows "tids" with a 1, and all the rows "tids" with a 2, and then intersect them.  Perhaps the intersection is small or zero once you are done, but it still took time to find them all before it could do the intersection.

Also how do you keep it correctly populated in the face of changes to transactions?  That is the difficulty with denormalized data.

If you don't want to add the denormalized column, you could instead do:

```
select o.*
from operations o
join (
  select operation_id, array_agg(user_id order by user_id) as user_ids
  from transactions t where user_id = ANY(array[1,2])
  group by operation_id
) t on t.operation_id = o.operation_id and user_ids @> array[1,2];
```

With an index on `transactions (user_id)`.  But again, if 1 and 2 each show up millions of times, the index would be of little use.

Comment: I'm thinking about a trigger that going to populate specific int array when the transaction is inserted for a specific operation. Can you explain in more detail, why the index is useless if there many duplicate array entries?

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase `work_mem` parameter to avoid physical merge sort.

```
SET work_mem TO '1 GB'
```

(adapting the value of course).

You could also try to specifiy a specific and large temp tablespace.
Typical commands :

```
CREATE TABLESPACE ts_temp OWNER postgres LOCATION '/path/to/server/dir';
ALTER DATABASE mydb SET temp_tablespaces TO ts_temp;
GRANT ALL ON TABLESPACE ts_temp to my_user;
```

See postgres doc for `temp_tablespaces`.

(edited after review of the comments)

Comment: I tried your SQL it's actually 2 times slower for the same data set as I showed in the query plan earlier.

Comment: This version was trying to avoid to sort the whole transaction table. But actually I see that the filter on line 11 removes almost all rows. Predicates seem to be pushed in the subquery (not stable ?). You should get the same performance with :
```select * from (
  select o.operation_id, array_agg(user_id order by user_id) as user_ids
  from operations o
  join transactions t on t.operation_id = o.operation_id
  where user_id in (1,2)
  group by o.operation_id
) t
where user_ids = array[1,2];```
Anyway, the main point remains : use a temp tablespace to avoid the (physical) merge sort.

Comment: Why would adding a new temp tablespace change anything?

Comment: Having a large temp tablespace can speed up merge sort. But actually, reading again this thread, i would just try to avoid physical sorting, increasing the work_mem parameter, for instance to 1 GB.

Comment: There is no limit on the size of the "temp tablespace" (apart from the capacity of the hard disk). Adding another tablespace won't change that.